# logic formula: transform to cnf / dnfb

Tags: predicate-logic

I try to transform some formulas into CNF and DNF but I am not sure how to use distributivity Law here.

Given:
$$ ((C \lor  D) \land (A\rightarrow D)) <-> (C \rightarrow A ) $$

I applied the rules for Implication and Biimplication and transformed it into NNF:

$$ (((\lnot C \land  \lnot D) \land (A\land \lnot D)) \lor \lnot C \lor A)  \land ((C \land \lnot A) \lor (C \lor D) \land (\lnot A \lor D)) $$

I knew that I have now to use Distributivity to get CNF and DNF, but I am not sure how to do it properly. I began with it and are already on the 2nd page, since I always get more Clauses :O.

Answer (score 0):

For an expression with just three variables, the easiest way is probably to write down the truth table. This directly represents the (non-optimized) `DNF`.

> CNF: d & (a+!c)
>
> DNF: ad + !cd

Karnaugh map:

```
             ac
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   0  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
d     +---+---+---+---+
   1  | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```

You get the `CNF` by looking at all terms with output value 0. Inverting all input literals gives you the `CNF` clauses.

Comment: Thank´s. But I would like to knew it with the rules since I cannot be sure that I always have three Variables. So, KV is not practicable.

Comment: For implication, you could translate "C implies A" to "A or not C" and apply the usual rules. Simililarly, you could translate bi-implication/equivalence into an and/or/not expression.

Comment: Heh? I have done that already in my starting Post. I only need to know how to apply Distibutivity Law.